# How to share data in social media app like as whatsapp, facebook using swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to share subject and message in social app like as whatsapp, facebook, twitter etc but below of code is not working. If social app is not installed to user app, it should be redirect to AppStore. kindly check my code.

```
static func sendWhatspp(msg:String)
{
    let urlWhats = "whatsapp://send?text=\(msg)"
    if let urlString = urlWhats.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed) {
        if let whatsappURL = NSURL(string: urlString) {
            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL as URL) {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(whatsappURL as URL)
            } else {
                AFWrapper.showError("Error!", msg: "WhatsApp is not Installed")
            }
        }
    }
}


static func sendTwitter(msg:String)
{
    let urlWhats = "twitter://send?text=\(msg)"
    if let urlString = urlWhats.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed) {
        if let whatsappURL = NSURL(string: urlString) {
            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL as URL) {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(whatsappURL as URL)
            } else {
                AFWrapper.showError("Error!", msg: "Twitter is not Installed")
            }
        }
    }
}

 static func sendFB(msg:String)
{
    let urlWhats = "facebook://send?text=\(msg)"
    if let urlString = urlWhats.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed) {
        if let whatsappURL = NSURL(string: urlString) {
            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL as URL) {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(whatsappURL as URL)
            } else {
                AFWrapper.showError("Error!", msg: "Facebook is not Installed")
            }
        }
    }
}

static func sendAll(msg:String)
{
    let urlWhats = "whatsapp://send?text=\(msg)"
    if let urlString = urlWhats.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed) {
        if let whatsappURL = NSURL(string: urlString) {
            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL as URL) {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(whatsappURL as URL)
            } else {
                AFWrapper.showError("Error!", msg: "No Share app Installed")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Kindly define "not working"

Comment: I strongly assume that Twitter and Facebook URLs don't start with "whatsapp://"

Comment: @MartinR when i am calling that function "sendWhatspp". it says to me "WhatsApp is not Installed" event it is installed in my iphone 6.

Comment: @MartinR yes. i am looking right url for sharing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no problem with your sendWhatsapp code. Did you add whatsapp into your Info.plist LSApplicationQueriesSchemes? You need to add for it to work.

To share on facebook and twitter. They are different

```
import Social 

if SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeFacebook) {
    var fbShare:SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)   
    self.presentViewController(fbShare, animated: true, completion: nil)
} else {
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Accounts", message: "Please login to a Facebook account to share.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)  
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Swift 4.0:

```
if SLComposeViewController.isAvailable(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook) {
        var fbShare:SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
        self.present(fbShare, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Accounts", message: "Please login to a Facebook account to share.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

For twitter: just replace SLServiceTypeFacebook with SLServiceTypeTwitter.

Comment: Thanks whatsapp is working now. But i am trying for twiiter and facebook. i added FB in info.plist.

Comment: "fb://send?text=\(msg)" i am using that url. i think it should be something differnet

Comment: Are you trying to share a post or send message through facebook messenger?

Comment: Just share a post on facebook app not messenger.

Comment: @RahulRawat I have edited my answer. Check it if it meets your requirements.

Comment: There is another way of sharing facebook post but u will need to import facebook sdk which enable you to share post and also send message through facebook messenger. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/sharing

Comment: yes it is working. but i need to use a message. rightnow it opens a dialog for share with empty text.

Comment: @RahulRawat you will need to use import facebook sdk and use the method provided from developer facebook website for that because fbShare.setInitialText() is not working at the moment.

Comment: fbShare.add(URL(string: msg)) i just needed url

Comment: Yup, addURL and addImage are both working but not setInitialText.